# How can I find the lowest and highest number in 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
package HighLow;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HighLow {
public static void main (String[]args) {
int [][] arr= new int[3][4];
int smallest=arr[0][0];
int largest= arr[0][0];
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
{
arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 12 numbers: ")); 
{
if (arr[i][j] < smallest) {
smallest = arr[i][j];
}
if (arr[0][0] > largest) {
largest = arr[i][j];
}
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The smallest value in the Array is:" + smallest);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The largest value in the Array is:" + largest);        
}

}

}}}
```

How can I find the lowest and highest number in 2d array?
I'm getting an error with my code? what seems to be wrong?
I just need to find the highest and lowest among the 12 numbers user will input. here is what I have so far.

How can I find the lowest and highest number in 2d array?
I'm getting an error with my code? what seems to be wrong?
I just need to find the highest and lowest among the 12 numbers user will input. here is what I have so far.

Comment: Is this line of your code throwing `java.lang.NumberFormatException`? `arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 12 numbers: "));`

Comment: Is there a reason for using a multidimensional array? It may be easier to consider using a single dimensional array like `int[] arr = new int[12];`

Comment: Yes that is what is showing

Comment: That is one of the requirements

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a loop to take in your array and therefore are receiving an error. To take in the input of the Array use this

```
for (int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    for (int j = 0;j<4;j++)
        arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 12 numbers: "));
```

Therefore you will have the box outputted 12 times for the user to input 12 Integers and then once you have the Array just run a simple sort to get the smallest and the largest.

```
int smallest  = arr[0][0];
int largest = arr[0][0];

for (int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    for (int j = 0;j<4;j++) {
        if (arr[i][j]<smallest)
            smallest = arr[i][j];
        else if(arr[i][j]>largest)
            largest = arr[i][j];
    }
}
```

Final Code being

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        int [][] arr= new int[3][4];

        for (int i = 0;i<3;i++)
            for (int j = 0;j<4;j++)
                arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 12 numbers: ")); 

        int smallest  = arr[0][0];
        int largest = arr[0][0];

        for (int i = 0;i<3;i++)
            for (int j = 0;j<4;j++) {
                if (arr[i][j]<smallest)
                    smallest = arr[i][j];
                else if(arr[i][j]>largest)
                    largest = arr[i][j];
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The smallest value in the Array is:" + smallest);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The largest value in the Array is:" + largest);        
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `JOptionPane` message be _Enter a number_, rather than _Enter 12 numbers_, since it is displayed 12 times?

Comment: It can be that or like a countdown of numbers left to input but it really is up to preference

Answer (score 0):

The error is mainly in the initialization part where you have assumed the element in the first row and first column to be either the minimum or maximum element in the array.

You have to initialize the minimum value of the array with a value that is sure to be higher than all the values in the array, why? because only then will there be an update to the actual minimum value of the array, so for example if you set minimum to be 1000 then if the actual minimum of the array is 300, it would get updated. But if you set your minimum to be for example 30 then 300 which is the actual minimum wont get logged and there would be an error.

The absolute opposite applies to the initialization of the largest value of the array. While initializing, safe ball park estimates usually work so carry out the initializations accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't think you should use `JOptionPane` to get data from the user and to display data to the user in a Java console application such as yours. I prefer to use [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html).

(Below code demonstrates. Notes after the code.)

Note that calling a method of `JOptionPane` will launch the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT) which means that your application will not terminate – unless you add `System.exit(0);`.

```java
package HighLow;

public class HighLow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter 12 numbers: ");
        String line = stdin.nextLine();
        String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        int k = 0;
        int[][] arr = new int[3][4];
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[k++]);
                if (arr[i][j] < smallest) {
                    smallest = arr[i][j];
                }
                if (arr[i][j] > largest) {
                    largest = arr[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The smallest value in the Array is: " + smallest);
        System.out.println("The largest value in the Array is: " + largest);
    }
}
```

1. I assume that the user enters twelve numbers separated by a space in a single line.
2. Method `split` returns an array of size twelve where every element is one of the entered numbers.
3. I initialize `smallest` to the largest `int` which guarantees that the first `int` that I compare it to is guaranteed to be smaller.
4. Similarly for `largest`. I initialize it to the smallest possible `int`.
5. You need a loop in order to populate all the elements of `arr`.

Here is output from a sample run of the above code.

```
Please enter 12 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 -1 -2
The smallest value in the Array is: -2
The largest value in the Array is: 9
```

### EDIT

Since you claim that `JOptionPane` is required, below code uses `JOptionPane`.

```java
String line = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter 12 numbers: ");
String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
int k = 0;
int[][] arr = new int[3][4];
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[k++]);
        if (arr[i][j] < smallest) {
            smallest = arr[i][j];
        }
        if (arr[i][j] > largest) {
            largest = arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The smallest value in the Array is:" + smallest);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The largest value in the Array is:" + largest);
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: However it is one of the requirements in my project -.-

Comment: @EC1 answer is edited to use `JOptionPane` as required and since it is required, perhaps you should make your application a [GUI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm) application rather than a console one.

Comment: I'm not familiar yet with that since I'm new in studying java. But I'll take note of this, I really appreciate the help.